# Forward traffic from one domain to another invisibly using CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have two domains:

- www.example.com

  - full admin application (access for managers and admins only)
  - sits behind original CloudFront distribution
  - assets hosted on amazon s3 as static website
  - api hosted on elastic beanstalk (ec2, elb, eb)
- www.new-example.com

  - small application for technicians to perform one function (upload document)
  - sits behind new CloudFront distribution
  - new origin and behavior to route api/* to the same ELB origin that www.example.com is routing to
  - assets hosted on amazon s3 as static website

Technicians will be using www.new-example.com, and my client doesn't want them to know about www.example.com.

www.new-example.com has no api; instead, I'd like to use the existing api at www.example.com.

Using CloudFront, how do I route requests from www.new-example.com/api/* to www.example.com/api/* in a way that never exposes the admin url?

**Update 1**

This is our auth request from the admin site, which successfully returns the correct payload:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.example.com/api/user/authenticate -d '{"email":"me@example.com", "password":"foobar1!"}'
```

When I submit using the new url, after some time, CloudFront throws a 504:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.new-example.com/api/user/authenticate -d '{"email":"me@example.com", "password":"foobar1!"}'
```

I know the CF behavior is working because if I replace 'api' with gibberish, it triggers the Default (*) behavior (only accepts GET/HEAD) which throws a different error.

Now I just need to figure out how to prevent the 504

Comment: I guess first things first -- did you already set up a second CloudFront distribution for the new domain and you're finding that somehow the URL ends up being rewritten to the other domain?  Or have you not set that up yet?

Comment: Have you tried simply using ‘new’ as a custom origin for the original?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I just updated my question. Yes, I have two separate distributions, and am trying to configure the path policies in the 'new' origin/behavior settings

Comment: @hephalump I considered that but got lost. I need requests to the root (new-example.com) to load the default index.html file from the new-example s3 bucket. I need requests to new-example.com/api/* to be routed to example.com. I got confused as to how to set that up.

Comment: You can setup multiple different behaviours with the first behaviour going to the S3 bucket, and the second routing to example.com.

Comment: ok so maybe I've already tried what you're suggesting @hephalump. I have two distributions, one for example, one for new. In my new distribution, I have two origins. then I have two behaviors, the default which points to the s3 origin, and the "api/*" pointing to the elb origin (same as what example.com is pointing to).